# java how to set an auto increment attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my entity I have this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
class Product{   
...
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int rank;
}
```

When I try to save an object of type product, in DB, the rank value remains always 0

Can I set an attribute other than the id auto-increment?

Comment: May be I miss understood your question... do you want map `rank` attribute value to a database sequence or auto generated number? This value needs to be set only once? Does this values can repeat itself between products?

Comment: Is that field an `@Id` field? Wont work if it isnt. And if it is then POST THE SQL invoked

Comment: @Carlitos, just an auto generated number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to auto generate a value, but they must always be done on the `@Id` field. If it is not declared, then you won't be able to auto increment your value.

There are different types of strategies to increment your Id. In this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers), you can learn more about them. For your example, IDENTITY should do the trick.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
class Product{   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int rank;
}
```

**Update**

After doing some research, it seems that Hibernate now allows to auto increment other non-id fields, but it uses another annotation for the purpose. I haven't tried it, but maybe it could work. This in case your rank is not your id.

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "column_name", insertable = false)
int rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @Alain Cruz, is the way! But it is the half of the answer... You will need:

1) To Modify your `rank` attribute like this:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "column_name", insertable = false)
Long rank;
```

2) Create a before insertion trigger that monitors `Products` entities, checking that if rank comes `null`, you will change that value for a new value returned by the desired sequence...

I have done this approach to generate special codes using SQL Functions stored in my database... You can find more info [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/generated/GeneratedValues.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
class Product{   
...
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    int rank;
}
```

Comment: @senior can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work and if it does not, then try what comes after:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
class Product{   
...
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int rank;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}



public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

If that does not work, then go to your database and set rank variable to be auto incremented.

Comment: This is not MY question. I simply pointed out an important error in your answer. There is no "missing" of any point in correcting you

Comment: That was a typo and that is why I said you are missing the point. We are trying to help here, and that is all. Please let us know if that has helped ?